# Bound on the size of the set of partial sums in a permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $n$ be a positive integer . If $\sigma$ is a permutation of the first $n$ positive integers , let $S(\sigma)$ be the set of all distinct sums of the form $\sum_{i=k}^{l} \sigma(i)$ where $1 \leq k \leq l \leq n$ .
Show that $|S(\sigma)|>\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{4\sqrt{2}}$ for all permutations $\sigma$ of the first $n$ positive integers .

Just to add some of my own insight:

I tried looking at it as $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\tfrac{3}{2}}$,now that $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ inspired me to go for [Erdos-Szekeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) and then kinda extrapolate to cube by merging it, i couldn't really go far on this.The problem does have quite a probabilistic vibe to it but that as well got me nowhere.

Comment: May I ask, where the problem comes from? Is it from a book, exercise sheet, or similar? Or is it your own conjecture and hence unclear wether true or not?

Comment: Oh yeah no problem it's Romanian TST 2015(team selection test) i just couldn't solve it  or find a solution